# numpy irregularly strided array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray) on numpy array structure in memory:

> Several algorithms in NumPy work on arbitrarily strided arrays.
>   However, some algorithms require single-segment arrays. When an
>   irregularly strided array is passed in to such algorithms, a copy is
>   automatically made.

What is an irregularly strided array?

Is this one --- `numpy.array([[1], [1,2]])`? If it's not, please provide an example of one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For instance:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> b = a[::2]
>>> b
array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

`a` is a single-segment array, with all the data closely packed next to each other in a single contiguous memory block. `b` on the other hand is a view into that same memory, with a stride that is twice the element size, skipping over the memory locations of the odd integers.

Being one of those functions that require a single-segment array, if you do `np.sort(b)`, it will first have to copy those chunks to a contiguous block of memory before actually get going with the actual sorting.

Comment: I see, irregularly strided array is a non-single-segment array. Thanks for the explanation.